# how to make div background limited to a certain area

Tags: css, background

I made a css example. The main parts where I am facing problems are:

```
#sign
{
 font-size: xx-large;
 color:white;
 background-color:blue;
 font-weight:bolder;
 text-align: right;
 position:right;
}
```

and I am implementing it like:

```
<div id="sign">Me and Me</div>
```

Here the background color is displayed like a band. Now I want the background color to be limited to only the text area "Me and Me". What modifications do I have to do to acheive this?

Comment: Your jsfiddle link is not complete.

Comment: please correct the jsfiddle link

Comment: do you want something like this >> http://jsfiddle.net/vMRzX/

Comment: Yes I want to show only the green colored background part and not the left side blue colored part to show!!

Comment: aare dood... you can edit the fiddle, play a lil to remove the bg-color... check this out >> http://jsfiddle.net/vMRzX/1/

Comment: @Bongs you can add that as an answer because I liked your short code style!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason that you can't just set the background for whichever elements you want styled?

---

Using [this link](http://www.dotvoid.com/2011/10/background-color-for-inline-text/) you can see that what you need is a `display: inline;` call. I wrote up a quick jsFiddle for you to look at, this should be what you want... 
http://jsfiddle.net/NjAUR/

---

Seeing that you want it on the right hand side, get rid of the `position: right` declaration, and use a `float: right`. Here is the updated version...
http://jsfiddle.net/NjAUR/1/

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I can delete it if you like. I was going to edit this answer to actually include the solution when he updated his jsFiddle or more accurately described what he's trying to do.

Comment: I've edited my post, it should look more like a proper answer now. Sorry about that, I know it's non-standard, but I don't really like comments.

Comment: I updated my post so it now displays on the right hand side. A small note: you might want to clear the float later on, you can use a `<br style="clear: both" />` tag, or if you want a more elegant solution, use the `:after` pseudo-element to do a cleafix. More details [here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline;` with your css. And if you need that in right side use `float:right` also.

See the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/randeep161/f3p4z/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Okay here I wrapped the "Me and Me" text inside a `span`. Removed `background-color` property of `#sign` and added it to the `span`.

HTML

```
<div id="sign"><span>Me and Me</span></div>​
```

CSS

```
#sign
{
    font-size: xx-large;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bolder;
    text-align: right;
    position:right;
}
#sign span { background-color:green; } /* or any color of your choice */
```

**[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/vMRzX/1/)**